# Significance of a close system propulsion

Tags: rocket-science, propulsion

I have an  idea of a close system propulsion powered by electricity. It can move mass in space without expelling anything. If this shall be proven to work, is this significant to the space flight industry now? Or does it need to have high efficiency value before it can be considered significant? How efficient should it be to be considered significant? Like for example, if my system can produce a 1 newton force from consuming 1 kilowatt hour power, is this significant? What is the highest level of efficiency so far that was achieved on this similar system?

Edit: I'll edit the question to be more objective as suggested by the moderator. What is the highest level of efficiency so far that was achieved on this similar system? So I shall know that if ever my idea works, I shall know that my example of 1 newton propulsion force using 1kwh power is significant or not.

Comment: If you have such a system, maybe try applying for a patent. Without context, I don't think anybody here will be able to answer your questions.

Comment: Are saying that it moves mass inside the same vehicle? ie., no mass/matter expelled?

Comment: @joseph. yes it moves mass in space without propellant but uses electricity.

Comment: does it propel anything _away_ from the vehicle?

Comment: @d_air Are you keeping the project secret? If not would you share it?

Comment: @Xfce4 I would really share it if it is proven to work and it is very important to the industry.

Comment: @d_air What do you need to prove it works?

Comment: @Xfce4 That is what I shall work on. But before I shall do that, I want to have an idea how to make it significant if it works. Like for example if it works but it can only produce a 0.01N force, would it be considered very significant? What level of efficiency shall the industry accept it as significant.

Comment: @d_air It is about what you want to achieve. 0.01N would be close to the force 1 gram (0.001 kg) of matter applying on your hand on earth surface, as F = mass x g where g = ~10 m/s^2 or ~ 10 N/kg.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it can move mass in space without expelling anything, then this means the mass being moved is either inside the vehicle, or on some part of the vehicle. This will not provide any propulsion since there are no *external* forces acting on the vehicle, nor is it transferring matter away from itself (like for example a rocket).

The total momentum of this, or any system remains constant, unless an *external* force is operating, and what you are describing i.e., "without expelling anything" implies there is no external forces operating and no change in momentum meaning no propulsion. So there does not appear to be any reason to talk about efficiency, since such a thing would not work.

Comment: I understand what you mean. But I've got this idea that no matter how I look, it really is feasible. I believe that many would think this as impossible. I've read from the internet that many attempted studying similar systems. But it's not clear for me that what they did  really work without doubt. So my question here is not if this idea is feasible but how significant would it be if this is proven to work in fact and without doubt.

Comment: Saying it would be "extremely significant" is still a huge understatement. But the laws of physics do not allow for such a device, and there is no doubt about it. Also note that it is really hard to go into detail if you stay vague on the nature of this device.